# Can we do payments in test mode using Apple Pay with stripe

Tags: ios, stripe-payments, applepay

I implemented Apple Pay with stripe.I used stripe test mode public key. When user clicked pay with Apple Pay, it showed a payment interface. I clicked pay with passcode and it generates a stripe token. It shows the payment is not completed. My doubt is can we do payments in test mode or we give real details for payment. Please give me clarity for that.

Comment: To void real payment during testing, you have to use sandbox, to know more -> https://developer.apple.com/support/apple-pay-sandbox/